# How to generate daily report of total bytes written (TBW,DWPD) to disk (SSD) in Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, ssd, administration, smartctl

What is the best way to get the correct value of *total bytes written* to disk per day?

My goal is to log it over time, so as an admin you can gain some sense of activity on a Linux Server and have a metric first hand that I can use to somewhat predict an SSD life expectancy... if cheaper consumer grade 1-DWPD can be used or for what you are doing you need to be using 3-DWPD enterprise class ssd's for example.

I am interested in the difference between XFS, EXT4, BTFS file system choices, as well as extra software/services installed in Linux, that might have an effect on SSD life.

**is there a better command than `smartctl` to capture the information I am looking for?**  I can write code to deal with this `--xall` extended output, or it there a better more specific smartctl option?

based on this output, what would value should I use to determine drive writes accurately?  I would do the following for disks 0..7 via `-d megaraid,#`.  This on on RHEL 8.9.

```
smartctl --xall -d megaraid,0 /dev/sda

smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-4.18.0-513.11.1.el8_9.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               TOSHIBA
Product:              KPM5WRUG3T84
Revision:             B318
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        3,840,755,982,336 bytes [3.84 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
LU is resource provisioned, LBPRZ=1
Rotation Rate:        Solid State Device
Form Factor:          2.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x58ce38ee20abca55
Serial number:        abc123
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS (SPL-3)
Local Time is:        Thu Mar  7 13:55:22 2024 EST
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported
Read Cache is:        Enabled
Writeback Cache is:   Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK

Percentage used endurance indicator: 0%
Current Drive Temperature:     29 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        70 C

Manufactured in week 33 of year 2019
Elements in grown defect list: 2

Error counter log:
           Errors Corrected by           Total   Correction     Gigabytes    Total
               ECC          rereads/    errors   algorithm      processed    uncorrected
           fast | delayed   rewrites  corrected  invocations   [10^9 bytes]  errors
read:          0        0         0         0          0      27081.068           0
write:         0        0         0         0          0       8041.818           0
verify:        0        0         0         0          0      23058.613           0

Non-medium error count:       87

SMART Self-test log
Num  Test              Status                 segment  LifeTime  LBA_first_err [SK ASC ASQ]
     Description                              number   (hours)
# 1  Background long   Completed                   -      38                 - [-   -    -]
# 2  Background short  Completed                   -      37                 - [-   -    -]
# 3  Background long   Completed                   -      14                 - [-   -    -]
# 4  Background short  Completed                   -      14                 - [-   -    -]

Long (extended) Self-test duration: 300 seconds [5.0 minutes]

Background scan results log
  Status: no scans active
    Accumulated power on time, hours:minutes 1169:17 [70157 minutes]
    Number of background scans performed: 0,  scan progress: 0.00%
    Number of background medium scans performed: 0

Protocol Specific port log page for SAS SSP
relative target port id = 1
  generation code = 4
  number of phys = 1
  phy identifier = 0
    attached device type: SAS or SATA device
    attached reason: unknown
    reason: loss of dword synchronization
    negotiated logical link rate: phy enabled; 12 Gbps
    attached initiator port: ssp=1 stp=1 smp=1
    attached target port: ssp=0 stp=0 smp=0
    SAS address = 0x58ce38ee20abca56
    attached SAS address = 0x52cea7f048bd6b07
    attached phy identifier = 1
    Invalid DWORD count = 12
    Running disparity error count = 12
    Loss of DWORD synchronization = 3
    Phy reset problem = 0
relative target port id = 2
  generation code = 4
  number of phys = 1
  phy identifier = 1
    attached device type: no device attached
    attached reason: unknown
    reason: unknown
    negotiated logical link rate: phy enabled; unknown
    attached initiator port: ssp=0 stp=0 smp=0
    attached target port: ssp=0 stp=0 smp=0
    SAS address = 0x58ce38ee20abca57
    attached SAS address = 0x0
    attached phy identifier = 0
    Invalid DWORD count = 0
    Running disparity error count = 0
    Loss of DWORD synchronization = 0
    Phy reset problem = 0
```

Comment: Have you tried ... you know ... running smartctl, ron? This works here for my NVMe: `smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1 | grep "Data Units Written"` @BarryCarter maybe I do. I can neither confirm nor deny it.

Comment: `grep -i "Data Units"` is blank

Comment: i revised the explanation above a bit.

Comment: the `Accumulated power on time` of **1170** hours, or 48 days, is not correct, this server with this disk is on 24/7 for the past 2+ years; it would be more believable if 1170 represented days not hours.

Comment: Your drive may have auto-sleep features which lowers the "power on" time. Or it could just be wrong

Comment: disregard my 1170 hours comment, those were new disks so that number is correct; smartctl shows 26804 hours (3.05 yrs) as expected when I look at those older disks